# How can I start building Neural Deep network using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm student, and still newbie in python, I need to use deep neural network in our field which is not related into  deep learning directly but we can use deep learning to optimize such errors.

I tried last time to work by python, but I found that I need long time to learn python from scratch. We are using Matlab 
for almost everything and I master it well. I decided to move back to matlab to use deep learning there,. my question, do anyone 
have any videos or tutorial I can follow to learn how deep learning in Matlab?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Deep learning** in layman term is a neural net with lots of neurons in many (deep) layers. Deep Learning Toolbox provides simple MATLAB commands for creating and interconnecting the layers of a deep neural network. Examples and pretrained networks make it easy to use MATLAB for deep learning, even without knowledge of advanced computer vision algorithms or neural networks.

**Try Deep Learning in 10 Lines of MATLAB Code**
This example shows how to use deep learning to identify objects on a live webcam using only 10 lines of MATLAB code.

1. Run these commands to get the downloads if needed, connect to the webcam, and get a pre-trained neural network.

```js
camera = webcam;  % Connect to the camera
net = alexnet;           % Load the neural network
```

If you need to install the webcam and alexnet add-ons, a message from each function appears with a link to help you download the free add-ons using Add-On Explorer. Alternatively, see Deep Learning Toolbox Model for AlexNet Network and MATLAB Support Package for USB Webcams.
After you install Deep Learning Toolbox Model for AlexNet Network, you can use it to classify images. AlexNet is a pre-trained convolutional neural network (CNN) that has been trained on more than a million images and can classify images into 1000 object categories (for example, keyboard, mouse, coffee mug, pencil, and many animals).

2. Run the following code to show and classify live images. Point the webcam at an object and the neural network reports what class of object it thinks the webcam is showing. It will keep classifying images until you press Ctrl+C. The code resizes the image for the network using imresize.

```js
while true
 im = snapshot(camera);       % Take a picture
 image(im);                   % Show the picture
 im = imresize(im,[227 227]); % Resize the picture for alexnet
 label = classify(net,im);    % Classify the picture
 title(char(label));          % Show the class label
 drawnow
end
```

I think the followings are good references for what you are looking for,

1. [Deep Learning in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/deep-learning-in-matlab.html)
2. [Time Series Forecasting Using Deep Learning](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/examples/time-series-forecasting-using-deep-learning.html)
3. [Sequence Classification Using Deep Learning](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/examples/classify-sequence-data-using-lstm-networks.html)